# Clicking on navigation drawer close itself Android studio

Tags: java, android

I have implemented navigation drawer on my mobile application and whenever i open the drawer and click on the drawer, the drawer closes itself. It used to work perfectly until I implemented another function and I am puzzled about how I should fix this.
Here's my main activity code. I am unable to navigate using the navigation drawer now.

```js
package com.example.admin.calendlist;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    ListView lstTask;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        lstTask = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstTask);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
        loadTaskList();

    }

    private void loadTaskList() {
        ArrayList<String> taskList = dbHelper.getTaskList();
        if(mAdapter==null){
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,R.id.task_title,taskList);
            lstTask.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        else{
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
         {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.action_add_task:
                 final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
                 AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                         .setTitle("Add New Task")
                         .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                         .setView(taskEditText)
                         .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                                 dbHelper.insertNewTask(task);
                                 loadTaskList();
                             }
                         })
                         .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                         .create();
                 dialog.show();
         }
             switch (item.getItemId()) {
                 case R.id.td:
                     Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                     return true;
             }
             switch (item.getItemId()) {
                 case R.id.tt:
                     Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,Timetable.class);
                     return true;
             }
             switch (item.getItemId()) {
                 case R.id.ep:
                     Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,EventPage.class);
                     return true;
             }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectItemDrawer(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
         if (id ==R.id.ep) {
             Intent newItent = new Intent (this, EventPage.class);
             startActivity(newItent);
         }
         else if (id == R.id.td) {
             Intent newIntent = new Intent (this,MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(newIntent);
         }
         else if (id == R.id.tt) {
             Intent newIntent = new Intent (this,Timetable.class);
             startActivity(newIntent);
         }
         DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    private void setupDrawerContent (NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener (new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                selectItemDrawer(item);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listmenu,menu);
        Drawable icon =menu.getItem(0).getIcon();
        icon.mutate();
        icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void deleteTask(View view){
        View parent = (View)view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
        dbHelper.deleteTask(task);
        loadTaskList();
    }

}
```

Comment: You call `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();` in `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: I've changed 
that bit of the code to
        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
and it is still closing

Comment: So what is your current code?

Comment: i've updated the code

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want navigation to close with each click, write like this :

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
navigationView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can use it after switch

    switch(id){

    }
//Set menuItem checked and title
     menuItem.setChecked(true);
  // close drawer when item is tapped
     mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

> its obvious in Default drawerlayout on your click it has to be close,if you wana get command on your drawerlayot , hen you have to use custom drawerlayout, or you can add the library, don't forget to import the library manually not in your gradle, then you can edit the library, and chose the functions . 
>   try this [Library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.Android)